# MySQL COUNT(*) performance

Tags: mysql, performance, count, query-performance

I have a table with more than 15m rows. I need the total number of rows. So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thetable;
```

Which takes around 50s to complete. Explaining gives me `Select tables optimized away`. I suppose this means that the result can be found only by using an index, then why does it still take so long? Here are some information about the index on the `id` column (It's non nullable):

> Index Type: BTREE (clustered)
>
> Cardinality: 14623100
>
> Unique: YES

How can I improve the performance of this query? Thanks.

Note: The database is MySQL 5.7.1 and using InnoDB engine.

**EDIT:**

**Create statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locality` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(13,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(13,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  .....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_properties_on_address` (`address`),
  KEY `index_properties_on_latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `index_properties_on_longitude` (`longitude`),
  KEY `index_properties_on_state` (`state`),
  KEY `index_properties_on_created_at` (`created_at`),
  .....
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28267712 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

Note: I omitted some lines, there are 44 columns.

**Explain plan:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered |            Extra             |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | NULL     | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: @lunr InnoDB count without any condition is [inherently slower](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/) as it has to go and count the rows one by one and check transactional visibility for each of them.

Answer (score 8):

Back when mysql was not transactionally sound by default (when people regularly used myISAM tables instead of InnoDB because that was the default or, going further back in time, because it didn't exist yet) "SELECT * FROM some_table" without any filtering clauses was one of the query types that peopel banged on about mySQL being much faster at that other database engines.

In a transactionally safe environment generally speaking the database engine will need to check every row and make sure that it should be visible to the current session (i.e. it isn't part of a transaction that is not yet committed (or wasn't committed at the start of this sessions active transaction) or is currently being rolled back) - checking every row implies needing to perform a table scan or (where one is present ) a clustered index scan.

It would be *possible* for the engine to keep track of the number of rows visible in each object for every active session/transaction, but presumably the designers have not judged this to be worth the extra processing involved so I assume it is not generally considered *practical* - I can imagine there would be some fairly complex locking requirements to deal with concurrency that would harm performance of other operations too much. You could implement this yourself by keeping a table in which is recorded the count of the rows in the table of interest, and have all your code meticulously maintain that value, but this would be quite some hassle and may be overly prone to errors due to bugs meaning that the count would drift from true over time (and you are probably adding a potential deadlock source and/or locking bottleneck at the application layer).

Situations where row-level security is in use complicate this even more - as well as needing to check the status of a row/page with respect to the current transaction, then engine needs to check again the current user too and as the security rules are dynamic it would be impractical to cache this information further necessitating the scan every time just-in-case. Row-level security is being added to MS SQL Server in the next release (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx) and is already present in postgres (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html), I don't know about its status in other RDBMSs.

Answer (score 6):

Complementing @david-spillett answer, you could change your query just by replacing the `count(*)` with a `count(id)` on your query, becoming:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM thetable;
```

Being because the `id` column not null, indexed (actually it's the primary key), which means that it's not null for all the rows and, as so, there are as many `id`s as there are rows.

But, even if you replace `count(*)` with `count(0)`, or `count("Hi, I'm a row")` you would have the same performance, because internally they result in the same operation. You can check it comparing the result of a `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...` on all the queries:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thetable;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT COUNT(id) FROM thetable;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT COUNT(0) FROM thetable;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT COUNT("Hi, I'm a row") FROM thetable;
```

Currently for InnoDB, `select count(<whatever>) from table_name ;`, without any conditions, is not the best practice.

This type of query performs better when:

1. Your smallest index on the table is on a very small column (a tinyint, for example) instead of a composed index or on a big column (like a `varchar(200)`), but don't add it just to improve this type of selects. That's because with a smaller index, InnoDB has less data to scan;
2. You add a `WHERE` criteria, narrowing the rows to count. This is your best option.

Comment: No. Check `EXPLAIN EXTENDED select count(*) from table_name; show warnings;` and you will see that `count(*)` is transformed to `count(0)` which is equivalent to `count(PK)` (or other not-null index). Actually any secondary InnoDB index can be used for that query (as they all contain the PK values) and it is usually faster than using the PK directly (less data to read).

Comment: Learning every day. But what's specifically wrong with my answer?

Comment: Well, the modification is not supposed to improve anything and imho `count(*)` is not a bad practice in itself. But reading it again if you meant `count without conditions` (no matter if `*` or `id`) then that would be a bad one :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I've improved my response, or at least I tried, given your input.

Comment: @jkavalik I agree. Edited the answer, because I thought the same thing as you, when I first read it, that *"`count(*)` is not best practise"*.

Comment: Another thing that is very easy to test in InnoDB. Make a wide table (say with some `VARCHAR` columns), a `table_id int PRIMARY KEY` and then add another index on `(table_id)`. The count queries would use that index instead of the PK index - because by definition that's the narrowest index you can have in an InnoDB table.

Comment: I still contend that `COUNT(*)` does whatever "is best", namely to do an index scan on the smallest index.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new table (properties_count (id, count)), and use trigger for insert (increment count) and for delete (decrement count).

After, you can use: select count from properties_count.

Answer (score 0):

if you could profile this query then we might have got more info on this issue. One thing for sure, the since the storage engine is InnoDB, the innodb buffers do have an impact.